# A corpus with semantic role tags for an NLP application

Tags: nlp, semantic-markup, corpus, tagged-corpus

So, I've constructed a NLP program that learns to extract a semantic event description from a sentence, but right now my training set is limited to sentences I've parsed into semantic event components my hand.

While this method does get the job done, its hardly a proper substitute for a large pre-parsed corpus of text. Unfortunately, all of my attempts at finding such a corpus have proven futile.

What I need specifically is a corpus that has tagged the semantic roles of each word (or group of words) in a sentence. Examples of roles I had in mind are things like:

- agent
- action
- patient
- instrument
- co-agent
- co-patient
- location
- adverb

If any more specifics are needed, feel free to ask, or refer to [this paper](http://psych.stanford.edu/~jlm/papers/StJohnMcC90.pdf) that uses a toy corpa with the same constraints as mine.

Comment: The word you want is 'corpus'. And they don't grow on trees, and are generally not available for free. Are you in an academic institution.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the catch; I was misspelling *and* pluralizing by mistake :(. Anyways, I'm associated with Stanford, so price isn't an issue.

Comment: Look at the treebanks at the LDC and see if they do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CoNLL Shared Task in 2005 was 'Semantic Role Labelling'. [This page](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~srlconll/spec.html) describes their corpus and what roles they labelled.

Comment: Nice Job! the CoNLL page led me to PropBank and FrameNet, which were exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!